# Displaying a lot of screens

Tags: android

I am starting to learn android development, I finished a couple of courses and now I am starting my own project.

So, my project is an travel app. There are four categories (in home screen, displayed in a scroll bar and constraint layout), and every category has 30 places (using recycler view to display all these places). To go to each category I will use Intent and new activity.

Now I want when the user clicks on a place, to be directed to a separate screen so the user can see more information about the place.(also images and where the place is on google maps)
So how to do this? I cannot create activities for all the places right?
Please help

I am using Kotlin

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When user click on any place then pass the all information related to that place with intent and receive it  all information in second activity  related to that place.. U don't need create separate activity for each..
Make sure you have good idea that how to pass data using intent ..if don't know then firstly learn it.